# java: A confusion about calling super method in the child class

Tags: java

The parent class and the child class is as follows.

```
public abstract class Dialog {

public void render() {
    // do something
    System.out.println(this.getClass());
    Button okButton = createButton();
    // for example, click "ok" button to close a dialog.
    okButton.onClick();
    okButton.render();
}

public Button createButton() {
    System.out.println("I'm a Button");
    return null;
}

}

public class WindowsDialog extends Dialog{

@Override
public Button createButton() {

    // do something
    System.out.println("I'm windows button");
    return new WindowsButton();
}

@Override
public void render() {
    super.render();
    System.out.println("I'm in the child class");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new WindowsDialog().render();
}
}
```

The execution result is:

```
class com.pattern.design.behavioral.method.factory.WindowsDialog
I'm windows button
I'm in the child class
```

I thought the invocation of createButton is `I'm a button` but it was not.

I want to know why the `this.getClass` is `WindowsDialog` and the invocation of 'createButton()'  is not `I'm a Button`.

Comment: Your code is printing the expected results. Why did you expect something different? and what is your confusion about `super`?

Comment: Ah I see. When you call `super.render()`, you are expecting that base class method to call other methods in the base class rather than the overrides in the derived clas. It doesn't do that. It only affects the actual `render` method itself.

Comment: Yes, but I want to know the reason or mechanism.

Comment: When you override a method from super class , it means that the current class (WindowsDialog) is now the boss and it will change the @Override method body , so the super class method can't execute .

Comment: This link can deeply help you -> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-in-java/

Comment: @OP The mechanism is that when you call a method it still calls the most overridden override available unless you have used `super.`. So when `Dialog.render()` calls `createButton()`, it calls `WindowsDialog.createButton()`. And so forth.

Comment: @ZahraAsgharzade It doesn't 'change the `@Override` annotation`. Nothing does.

Comment: @ZahraAsgharzade Well, this website is pretty useful for me!